# Make R code more concise for creating indicator of overlapping dates

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse

I have a dataset which contains several rows per `id`. Each row contains a `start` date and `end` date for an activity. I want to create an indicator for each row (activity) that denotes whether it overlapped with another activity from the same person (id).

So far, I have managed to do this in R successfully. However, I feel as though my code is not very concise. I suspect I may be able to do this with shorter forloops or by using a combination of `mutate()`, `ifelse()` and other window functions from the `dplyr` and `lubridate` libraries.

Here is my code for a minimal reproducible example:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(6202924, 6202924, 6202924, 6202924, 6202924, 
6202924, 6202924, 6203161, 6202802, 6202781, 6202781, 6202760, 
6202890, 6203223, 6202766, 6203154, 6202891, 6202891, 6202876, 
6202876, 6203075, 6202988, 6202805, 6202741, 6203144, 6203144, 
6203144, 6203051, 6203140, 6203140, 6203140, 6203140, 6203140, 
6203140, 6203115, 6202870, 6202870, 6202870, 6203180, 6203180, 
6203180, 6202968), start = structure(c(NA, 14890, 14944, 14883, 
14914, 14958, 14982, 14860, NA, 14867, 14867, NA, 14853, 14860, 
15102, NA, NA, 14883, 14853, 14853, 14853, 14860, 14853, 14853, 
15065, NA, NA, NA, 15048, 14867, 14928, 14853, 14853, 14867, 
14914, 14975, 15013, 15013, NA, 14982, 15065, 14982), class = "Date"), 
    end = structure(c(NA, 14965, 14965, 14965, 14965, 14958, 
    14982, 15208, NA, 14874, 14874, NA, 15208, 15208, 15102, 
    NA, NA, 14904, 15147, 14965, 15208, 15027, 15208, 15208, 
    15208, NA, NA, NA, 15048, 15208, 14965, 15208, 15006, 14874, 
    14935, 14975, 15048, 15048, NA, 15079, 15208, 15208), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -42L), .Names = c("id", 
"start", "end"))

df1 <- df %>%
  arrange(id, start, end) %>% # Order chronologically
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(seq = row_number(), # An indicator of the seq of activity per id
         count = n(), # An indicator of total number of activities per id
         overlap = "No") %>% #Indicator of overlap
  ungroup()

for(i in 1:nrow(df1)) { 

  # This loop compares the index row to the row below it
  if(df1$end[i] >= df1$start[i + 1] &
     df1$id[i] == df1$id[i + 1] &
     !is.na(df1$end[i]) &
     !is.na(df1$start[i + 1])) {

    df1$overlap[i] <- "Yes"

  }

  if(i != 1 & df1$seq[i] != 1) {

    for(j in 1:(df1$seq[i] - 1)) {
      # This loop compares the index row to the rows behind it which also belong to the same id
      if(df1$start[i] <= df1$end[i - j] &
         df1$id[i] == df1$id[i - j] &
         !is.na(df1$end[i - j]) &
         !is.na(df1$start[i])) {

        df1$overlap[i] <- "Yes"
        break
      }
    }

  }

}
```

I really love the `tidyverse` suite of libraries, so first prize for me would be if someone could help me find a way to do this using those libraries.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using only `dplyr`:

We can take use of the `join` property that, given duplicate ids, they produce all possible combinations of rows. This approach is quadratic in memory, though, so some additional optimization might be needed if you have millions of rows.

First, add an id number to each activity:

```
dfi = mutate(df, act_id=seq_along(id))
```

Then produce all possible combinations of activities for each user (merge dataframe with itself), remove rows where the same activity is in both columns, and keep the ones overlapping in time: (note that we only need to check one-sided overlap, with `x` starting before `y`)

```
df2 = inner_join(dfi, dfi, by="id") %>%
    filter(act_id.x!=act_id.y,
           start.x<=start.y,
           start.y<=end.x)
```

To produce a vector of overlapping activity ids:

```
ovrl_ids = c(df2$act_id.x, df2$act_id.y)
```

Or a logical column for the original dataframe:

```
dfi$ovrl = dfi$act_id %in% ovrl_ids
```

Confirming that the results match `df1` produced by your solution:

```
dfb = full_join(df1, dfi, by=c("id", "start"))
table(dfb$ovrl, dfb$overlap, useNA="a")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `IRanges` package from Bioconductor. In order to install it:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("IRanges")
```

Thus we need three packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(IRanges)
```

`IRanges` doesn't like `NA` values, and we want to isolate them. First we identify each row of the `data.frame`:

```
df <- df %>%
  arrange(id, start, end) %>%
  mutate(i = 1:n())
```

and then find overlaps for `!NA` values:

```
overlaps <- df %>%
  na.omit() %>%     # Get rid of NAs
  group_by(id) %>%
  do({
    # In .data we have data block for each id
    .data <- .

    # We only find overlaps for ids with more than 1 record
    if (nrow(.data) > 1) {
     .data %>%
       group_by(i) %>%
       do({
        .byi <- .

        # Here we define ranges for i and for all except i
        full_range <- .data %>% filter(i != .byi$i) %$% IRanges(as.numeric(start), as.numeric(end))
        this_range <- .data %>% filter(i == .byi$i) %$% IRanges(as.numeric(start), as.numeric(end))

        # Count overlaps here
        data_frame(overlap = countOverlaps(this_range, full_range) > 0)
       })
    } else {
      .data %>% select(i) %>% mutate(overlap = FALSE)
    }
  })
```

After that we need to merge our overlaps back to original data:

```
result <- df %>% 
  left_join(overlaps, by = c("i", "id")) %>%
  mutate(overlap = ifelse(is.na(overlap), FALSE, overlap)) %>%
  select(-i)
```

Results are the same as in basic `for-loop` solution:

```
> result
# A tibble: 42 × 4
        id      start        end overlap
     <dbl>     <date>     <date>   <lgl>
1  6202741 2010-09-01 2011-08-22   FALSE
2  6202760       <NA>       <NA>   FALSE
3  6202766 2011-05-08 2011-05-08   FALSE
4  6202781 2010-09-15 2010-09-22    TRUE
5  6202781 2010-09-15 2010-09-22    TRUE
6  6202802       <NA>       <NA>   FALSE
7  6202805 2010-09-01 2011-08-22   FALSE
8  6202870 2011-01-01 2011-01-01   FALSE
9  6202870 2011-02-08 2011-03-15    TRUE
10 6202870 2011-02-08 2011-03-15    TRUE
# ... with 32 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `dplyr` and `lubridate` only (i.e., `tidyverse` only).

The tricky part (most of the code below) is actually to build `mycombs` which contains, for each activity (with a new id `nid`), all the combinations with  the other activities from the same person (`id`), and which also contains the `start` and `end` date of the second activity (to which the first one should be compared).
Once you have it, you can simply `left_join` the two data.frames and check whether there is an overlap between the activities for each of the combinations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

newDF = df %>% mutate(grouplabel=as.integer(factor(id))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% mutate(nid = paste(id, row_number(), sep='-')) %>% ungroup()

# Split the activities per person and keep only where there is >1 activity
mygroups = split(newDF$nid, newDF$grouplabel)
mygroups = mygroups[lapply(mygroups,length)>1] 

# Find all the possible comparisons between the activities (per person)
mycombs = lapply(mygroups, function(x) expand.grid(x,x) %>% filter(Var1!=Var2))
mycombs = do.call(rbind, mycombs)
mycombs = data.frame(nid=mycombs[,1], nid2=mycombs[,2]) # Convert to data.frame

# Associate the start and end dates of the second activity of each combination
mycombs$start2 = as.Date(sapply(mycombs$nid2, 
                                function(x) return(newDF[newDF$nid==x,]$start)), 
                         origin = origin)
mycombs$end2 = as.Date(sapply(mycombs$nid2, 
                              function(x) return(newDF[newDF$nid==x,]$end)), 
                         origin = origin)

# merge the two data.frames and check wheter there is an overlap for each combination
myDF = left_join(newDF, mycombs, by='nid') %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(toverlap = as.period(intersect(new_interval(start, end), 
                                        new_interval(start2, end2)), 
                              "days"),
         overlap = !is.na(toverlap))
```

Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be considered a slight simplification:

```
# define own function which takes dataframe and for a given id calculates the overlaps
test <- function(id, data, startCol = "start", endCol = "end", idCol = "id")
{
        temp <- 0
        # if given id in dataframe more than once
        if(nrow(data[data[, idCol] == id, ]) > 1)
        {
                temp <- colSums(
                                # given interval within some other interval
                                sapply(unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, startCol]),">=", unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, startCol])) * 
                                      sapply(unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, endCol]),"<=", unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, endCol])) +
                                        # given interval starts before some other ends
                                      sapply(unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, startCol]),"<=", unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, endCol])) *
                                        # And ends after the other starts
                                      sapply(unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, endCol]),">=", unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, startCol])) +
                                        # given interval starts before other ends
                                      sapply(unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, startCol]),"<=", unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, endCol])) *
                                        # And ends after other ends
                                      sapply(unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, endCol]),">=", unlist(data[data[, idCol] == id, endCol])), na.rm = TRUE)
        }
        temp
}

# create a placeholder for overlaps
df$overlap <- "No"
# overwrite where there is some overlap 
# >3 is there because definition of overlaps above says that interval overlaps itself
df$overlap[unlist(sapply(unique(df$id), test, df)) > 3] <- "Yes"
```

And if you first convert df to data.frame you should be able to drop all the `unlists` inside `sapply`